# inline radio buttons using div

Tags: html, css

I have below code for radio buttons .But buttons are not displaying inline.it is in listed format.

I want to show it in a same line.how to modify it in oder to display both icons in same line.

```
<div class="abcd" id="radioPanel">

                                    <div style="width:100%;" >
                                        <input type="radio">
                                        </input>
                                        <label for="selectId">abc</label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div style="width:100%;" >
                                    <input type="radio">
                                        </input>
                                        <label for="frId">asd</label>
                                    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you have a problem which is reproducible using pure HTML/CSS then you should not focus on the server side code which generates that HTML/CSS code (as you would still have had exactly the same problem with any other server side language generating the same HTML/CSS code such as ASP/PHP/etc), but you should instead focus on the generated HTML/CSS code. Hence it's removed from the question in order to reduce irrelevant noise for HTML/CSS experts here. For the next time, you can find it yourself by simply right-clicking the page in webbrowser and choosing "view page source".

Answer (score 0):

And why not you let it in one div?

```
<div class="abcd" id="radioPanel">
   <div style="width:100%;" >
      <input type="radio"></input>
      <label for="selectId">abc</label>
      <input type="radio"></input>
      <label for="frId">asd</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Input's parents are block elements and 100% width..
Or also you can use change divs style and instead of `width:100%;` put `display:inline`

Answer (score 0):

To display radio buttons in the same line, you can use CSS to set the display property of the radio input and label elements to inline or inline-block.

```
<style>

    .abcd input[type="radio"],
    .abcd label {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin-right: 10px; 
    }

</style>

<div class="abcd" id="radioPanel">
    <div style="width:100%;" >
        <input type="radio" id="selectId">
        <label for="selectId">abc</label>
    </div>

    <div style="width:100%;" >
        <input type="radio" id="frId">
        <label for="frId">asd</label>
    </div>
</div>
```